Avoid vocabulary revisions
it seems to me that it's not possible to fully avoid revisions in taxonomy: even if I uncheck "Create new revision" for a specific vocabulary, one revision is always created for each term, doubling unusefully the space for storing terms.
Or is there a way?
thanks

Taxonomy terms were made revisionable during the development of Drupal 8.
When an entity type (such as taxonomy terms) is made revisionable, as you note, there will always be one revision created, even if you do not check Create new revision.
There is no way to disable this behavior; if you want something like taxonomy terms but you do not want them to be revisionable, you will need to create your own entity type and implement all the relevant features yourself (it almost certainly won't be worth it to take this approach).
